# The quantity of elements in array which difference will be equal some value. But not using double foreach(or for)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have some array with integer elements. For example (20, 5, 7, 143 , 25, 244, 148). And have a condition: that the difference between elements is 5. Thats why in this array the the quantity will be 2, because I have only two pairs 20,25 and 143, 148, because 25-20 = 5 and 143-148 = 5 too.
Ofcourse I can use foreach and in it again use foreach and compare the difference of all elements; and count it. But it have difficulty(N*N). I need to find another solution.

**EDIT. Solved.** 
First : subtract $difference Int from all elements in initial array, and set the result values in new array, and after that use in_array() and count the quantity.

Comment: If the elements are not sorted, the best you could do is to loop over the array and check the elements value with all later elements (you don't need to do a full internal loop, only loop over everything after the outer loop. When the outer loop is on number 5, start the inner loop on number 7). The other option is to sort, then you can just check each element with the next one.

Comment: You might also be able to do a simple lookup - if you're looking at the element '20', you don't need to loop through the rest of the array, when all you need to do is see if there's a value with 15 or 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one trick you can do here is to subtract 5 (difference between elements) from all elements in initial array, so you will have new array
e.g.

```
int[] initialArray = {20, 5, 7, 143, 25, 244, 148};
int[] newArray = {15, 0, 2, 138, 20, 239, 143};
```

got the idea ? :)
we if not, then what is left to do is iterate over your new array and check whether such element exist in initial array this is O(n) complexity operation since you iterate over array one time and checking whether initial array contains given element is O(1).
if you code in php use in_array() function, if you use java then instead of array use Map that has contains method.